# Drupal7, draggable menu reordering missing, weight dropdowns instead

Tags: 7, routes

My client cannot see the draggable arrows next to menu items in the list view, while I can. I checked the cookies and it appears he is missing a cookie that I have in my browser:

> Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it looks quite promising.

We are both using Google Chrome 13.

Has anyone experienced this problem before, is there a way to force Drupal to regenerate the cookie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has your client accidentally clicked on "Show/hide row weights" in the top right corner of the menu list?

Comment: Hi Nigel, Thanks, so obvious now that you mention it!

Comment: haha. hm. it should've been named show/hide drag handles, too.